# Chef client bootstraping with the wrong ethernet interface

Tags: chef-infra, centos6, knife

Hi I am bootstrapping a new server node to my chef environment, but on this particular machine, I have 2 Ethernet interfaces, and when I bootstrap this machine, always get the wrong interface for this machine.

Is that any parameter that can be passed to force the bootstrapping process to ignore an interface or to use a specific interface on this process?

-- edit

Basically, this server that I want to bootstrap is my PBX manager server, it has 2 Ethernet connections, eth0 that connects all internal phones and eth1 that connects to the rest of my network, so all my clients can authenticate with softphones, and where the rest of my servers are.

When I run the command to bootstrap, this server appears on the server nodes list, but with the wrong IP. Follow the command I execute, and a SS from my server network configuration and my Chef result.

```
knife bootstrap 192.168.56.102 --ssh-user pbxmngusr --identity-file ./key --node-name pbxmngr
```

[image: Server network interfaces]

[image: Chef Manager screen. The yellow one is my server with the wrong IP]

Comment: What do you mean by "get the wrong interface" ?

Comment: This particular server has 2 ethernet connections, on eth0, this server connects to my pbx network, on eth1, connects to my main network, where all the other servers are located. When I bootstrap, It always get the eth0 IP while bootstrapping, when it need to get eth1 IP.

Comment: Fix your DNS, or bootstrap by IP... I assume you're saying Knife tries to connect to the wrong IP, if not, explain yourself better and show logs.

Comment: Sorry if I wasn't clear enough, but when I bootstrap, I pass the "correct" ip address, from eth1 192.168.56.X:

     knife bootstrap 192.168.56.102 --ssh-user pbxmngusr --identity-file ./key --node-name pbxmngr

But it always get IP of the eth0 10.0.2.15.

Comment: Where do you get this IP ? Take some time to [edit] your question with clear information with what you're doing, what you obtain and where... It's impossible to guess what you have on your prompt from here...

Comment: @Tensibai check out the information I added to the question.

Comment: Well, the IP address saved by chef on the node object is eth0 address (usually the principal address), you'll find the other interfaces address under network => interfaces. What is your problem at all finally ? If you really want the 192.168.x.x address to be the main, inverse your network configuration and cables...

Comment: When this happen, my node won't show up on the node list. To see this node on the list, I have to access it's complete URL like https://CHEF_DNS/organizations/ORGANIZATION_NAME/nodes/pbxmngr

If I try to list it with just https://CHEF_DNS/organizations/ORGANIZATION_NAME/nodes    it won't show up.

Comment: So the problem is absolute something else. Run a `chef-server-ctl reindex` on your chef server and it will appear in the list.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/130624/discussion-between-paulo-gomes-and-tensibai).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are seeing in the web ui there is the `ipaddress` node attribute from Ohai. Chef itself doesn't care about this value, in situations with multiple interfaces it tries to use the address corresponding to the default route. You can find all interfaces under `node["network"]["interfaces"]` if you need to do more complex operations.